# what does this matlabe code mean?

Tags: matlab

A is just a observed matrix. I cannot find the meaning of this "@(x) A*x ". Anyone 
can explain this code for me? What is it used for?

```
if iscell(A)
        LARGESCALE  = true;
        Af  = A{1};
        At  = A{2};     % we don't really need this...
    else
        LARGESCALE  = false;
        Af  = @(x) A*x;
        At  = @(x) A'*x;
    end
```

Comment: look for anonymous functions http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100595/what-is-operator-in-matlab?lq=1

Comment: what is the meaning of Af and At here?

Comment: if you dont understand what `A*x` or `A'*x` are, I suggest you read basic matlab documentation. the `{}` brackets suggest that a cell type variable is used (as `iscell` suggests before).