# "Invalid Handle Object" when plotting 2 figures Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, animation, graph, plot

I'm having a difficult time understanding the paradigm of Matlab classes vs compared to c++.  I wrote code the other day, and I thought it should work.  It did not... until I added

```
<handle
```

after the classdef.

So I have two classes, landmarks and robot, both are called from within the simulation class.  This is the main loop of obj.simulation.animate() and it works, until I try to plot two things at once.

DATA.path is a record of all the places a robot has been on the map, and it's updated every time the position is updated.

When I try to plot it, by uncommenting the two marked lines below, I get this error:

**??? Error using ==> set
Invalid handle object.**

Error in ==> simulation>simulation.animate at 45
                set(l.lm,'XData',obj.landmarks.apparentPositions(:,1),'YData',obj.landmarks.apparentPositions(:,2));

```
%INITIALIZE GLOBALS
global DATA XX
XX = [obj.robot.x ; obj.robot.y];
DATA.i=1;
DATA.path = XX;

%Setup Plots
fig=figure;
xlabel('meters'), ylabel('meters')
set(fig, 'name', 'Phil''s AWESOME 80''s Robot Simulator')
xymax = obj.landmarks.mapSize*3;
xymin = -(obj.landmarks.mapSize*3);
l.lm=scatter([0],[0],'b+');
%"UNCOMMENT ME"l.pth= plot(0,0,'k.','markersize',2,'erasemode','background'); % vehicle path
axis([xymin xymax xymin xymax]);


%Simulation Loop
for n = 1:720,
    %Calculate and Set Heading/Location
    XX = [obj.robot.x;obj.robot.y];
    store_data(XX);
    if n == 120,
        DATA.path
    end
    %Update Position
    headingChange = navigate(n); 
    obj.robot.updatePosition(headingChange); 
    obj.landmarks.updatePerspective(obj.robot.heading, obj.robot.x, obj.robot.y);

    %Animate
    %"UNCOMMENT ME" set(l.pth, 'xdata', DATA.path(1,1:DATA.i), 'ydata', DATA.path(2,1:DATA.i));
    set(l.lm,'XData',obj.landmarks.apparentPositions(:,1),'YData',obj.landmarks.apparentPositions(:,2));
    rectangle('Position',[-2,-2,4,4]);
    drawnow
```

This is the classdef for landmarks

```
classdef landmarks <handle
properties
    fixedPositions;  %# positions in a fixed coordinate system. [ x, y ]
    mapSize;  %Map Size.  Value is side of square
    x;
    y;
    heading;
    headingChange;
end
properties (Dependent)
    apparentPositions
end
methods
    function obj = landmarks(mapSize, numberOfTrees)
        obj.mapSize = mapSize;
        obj.fixedPositions = obj.mapSize * rand([numberOfTrees, 2]) .* sign(rand([numberOfTrees, 2]) - 0.5);
    end
    function apparent = get.apparentPositions(obj)
        currentPosition = [obj.x ; obj.y];
        apparent = bsxfun(@minus,(obj.fixedPositions)',currentPosition)';
        apparent = ([cosd(obj.heading)  -sind(obj.heading) ; sind(obj.heading)  cosd(obj.heading)] * (apparent)')';
    end
    function updatePerspective(obj,tempHeading,tempX,tempY)
        obj.heading = tempHeading;
        obj.x = tempX;
        obj.y = tempY;
    end
end
end
```

To me, this is how I understand things.  I created a figure l.lm that has about 100 xy points.  I can rotate this figure by using

```
set(l.lm,'XData',obj.landmarks.apparentPositions(:,1),'YData',obj.landmarks.apparentPositions(:,2));
```

When I do that, things work.  When I try to plot a second group of XY points, stored in DATA.path, it craps out and I can't figure out why.

I need to plot the robots path, stored in DATA.path, AND the landmarks positions.  Ideas on how to do that?

Jonas:
I'm not saying you're wrong, because I don't know the answer, but I have code from another application that plots this way without calling axes('NextPlot','add');

```
if dtsum==0 & ~isempty(z) % plots related to observations
    set(h.xf, 'xdata', XX(4:2:end), 'ydata', XX(5:2:end))
    plines= make_laser_lines (z,XX(1:3));
    set(h.obs, 'xdata', plines(1,:), 'ydata', plines(2,:))
    pfcov= make_feature_covariance_ellipses(XX,PX);
    set(h.fcov, 'xdata', pfcov(1,:), 'ydata', pfcov(2,:)) 
end
drawnow
```

The above works on the other code, but not mine.  I'll try implementing your suggestion and let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call plot multiple times on the same figure, the previous plot is by default erased, and the handle to the previous plot points to nothing. Thus the error.

To fix this, you need to set the `NextPlot` property of the axes to `add`. You can do this by calling `hold on` (that's what you'd do if you were plotting from command line), or you can write

```
fig=figure;
%# create a set of axes where additional plots will be added on top of each other 
%# without erasing
axes('NextPlot','add');
```

If you want, you can store the axes handle as well, and use `plot(ah,x,y,...)` to make sure that you plot into the right set of axes and not somewhere strange if you happen to click on a different figure window between the time the figure is opened and the plot command is issued.

Comment: Can I also set 'hold on' for each axis or is that for the entire figure or nothing.

Comment: Hold on works for the current axes. If there is no current axes, Matlab creates a set of axes and sets its `NextPlot` property to `add`. `hold on` and `hold of` are simply shortcuts for `set(gca,'NextPlot','add')` and `set(gca,'NextPlot','replace')`. `gca` gets the handle of the current axes, i.e. the axes you last clicked on, or the first axes in the last figure you clicked on.

Comment: That worked great.  Thanks...  Are there any good resources for someone experienced with programming but not with matlab?  This language seems very quirky...

Comment: @pinnacler: Stackoverflow is pretty good, since programmers usually know how to ask questions, and good questions get fast answers. Also, the Matlab documentation is very useful. Furhtermore, I give a presentation about Matlab to programmers next Tuesday (see also this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691569/matlab-tutorial-for-programmers), and if you want to come over to Montral, you're very welcome :). If you contact me via my page at the Mathworks file exchange, I can send you what I'm presenting. It may be a good start.

Comment: How much is the workshop in Montreal?  I may make the trip... seriously.  I'm in Boston, that's the closest I'll ever be.

Comment: @pinnacler: Thanks for the confidence! I sincerely doubt, though, that my tiny tutorial is worth the money for a trip. You're likely to be better served by an official workshop from The Mathworks, for example on May 24/25: http://www.mathworks.com/services/training/schedule.html?courseNum=&format=Instructor_Led&location=&date=12_months&find_classes=Find+Classes&s_cid=HP_T_LC